# Fastlane iOS tests pass locally but not from Jenkins

Tags: ios, jenkins, fastlane

I have some trouble with Fastlane execution on Jenkins. 
Locally it works, build succeed and tests run. 
But from Jenkins and github, the build don't succeed. 
I think it's because of this line :

```
PhaseScriptExecution Run\ Script /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-bljizzbrhfznjpgjucmtarcsjmyw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyProject.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Core.build/Script-FC957A9020120D68000F4790.sh
```

But not focus on that, I'm not sure that's it.

Here the Fastfile :

```
default_platform(:ios)

platform :ios do
desc "Launch Middleware tests"
lane :tests do
  run_tests(workspace: "MyProject.xcworkspace",
            clean: true,
            devices: ["iPhone 8"],
            scheme: "Middleware",
            slack_url: "https://hooks.slack.com/services/...",
            slack_channel: "#myChannel")
  end
end
```

Some environment variables set
[image: Environment variables]

The Build action :
 [image: Build action]

The jenkins error
[image: jenkins error]

The command created by fastfile and executed by Jenkins

[image: Fastlane command]

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer, it appears that is that script : Script-FC957A9020120D68000F4790.sh, I was using sourcery before Swift 4.

```
${PODS_ROOT}/Sourcery/bin/sourcery --sources ${PROJECT_DIR}/Core --templates ${PROJECT_DIR}/Sourcery/Core/Templates --output ${PROJECT_DIR}/Core/Sourcery/
```

Jenkins was not able to find PODS_ROOT and PROJECT_DIR environment variables. I don't use sourcery anymore so, I commented that script but if you still use it, I think you can add environment variables to jenkins configuration

Comment: thanks for mentioning script name, it borned the idea to compare the error I got and check the file.